# FESTO Designer Studio for CDPX HMI

Tags: automation

Is anyone have experience with FESTO Designer Studio.

Issues:
1, Unable to configure the Table with 1D Array of LREAL.
2, Unable to get Tag, when PLC array is Created with Array OF STRUCT.

Need to Communicate FESTO HMI CDPX with FESTO PLC for Array of STRUCT.